# Why does glibc redefine structs already defined by the linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, glibc

The kernel defines **struct statfs** in [statfs.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/statfs.h).

glibc could simply include this file. Instead it redefines this struct under bits/statfs.h.

I suppose glibc redefines many other things already defined by the kernel.

Why is that?

Comment: The kernel shouldn’t need a libc to build, and glibc doesn’t need the Linux kernel to build.  Kernel struct data structures are used differently than those used in libc.

Comment: @jsbillings glibc [needs the headers from a Linux kernel](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Linux.html).